# use one main domin for two project in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have two react projects and I would like to run both on aws amplify.

First project deploys on `subdomain.maindomain.com` And its ok.

So I would like to deploy the second project to `maindomain.com`.It's possible? I tried like that but I can't call this main domain.

> Update

Here is Route 53.I created one hosted zone.

[image]

Here is inside of Route 53.

[image]

Here is the main react app's domain management

[image]

Here is sub domain react app's domain management

[image]

Comment: This is definitely possible. What is the specific issue you are running into?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth, Let me explain all process, At first, my domain is in GoDaddy and not active yet and then I change name server to AWS 53 . I deployed my first react app to subdomain.maindomain.com and It pretty well.and then I would like to deploy another react app to maindomain.com. "This site can't be reached" is show.

Comment: Do you have records in Route 53 pointing to the root? You would need one entry for `subdomain.maindomain.com` and a second record for `maindomain.com`.

Comment: At route 53, I created one hosted zone with main domain.

Comment: Can you show the Route 53 records? Block out the sensitive information.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth, Check the update.Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have a CNAME record for your sub-domain. Is the A record on the domain pointing to the same place? What is hosting this website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207723/discussion-between-loran-and-jason-wadsworth).